# PDO lastInsertID() failing due to running multiple queries in a single call

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This is odd. I'm running a query with just a single INSERT, preceded by a SET statement. The query looks something like this:

```
SET @discount:=(SELECT discount * :applyDiscount FROM fra_cus WHERE customerID=:customerID AND franchiseID=:franchiseID);

INSERT INTO discounts_applied (unitID, franchiseID, customerID, amount)
    VALUES(:unitID, :franchiseID, :customerID, @discount * :price);
```

It appears that if I prepare these as two separate PDO queries, lastInsertID() works fine... but if I prepare them and execute them in the same statement, lastInsertID() returns nothing.

It's not the end of the world, but it's annoying. Anyone know why this would be the case? For the record, there's a reason I need to define @discount as a variable (pertains to triggers on one of the tables). Also this is all taking place within a larger transaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I would **strongly recommend** to run every query in a distinct API call. This is how an Application Programming Interface is **intended** to work.

It won't only prevent situations like this but also will make your code a multitude times more readable and maintainable.

**And it will make your code much safer too**. You can run multiple statements in a single call only at the expense of the native prepared statements. However virtual this vulnerability is, why taking chances at all?

Why not to make a regular SELECT query instead of SET, get the resulting value into a PHP variable and then use it among other variables, just through a placeholder? I don't see any reason why there should be such a complex way to deal with simple data.

In case I failed to convince you, the reason is simple. You are running **two** queries, and the first one doesn't trigger any insert ids. And obviously, you need this  query's metadata (errors, affected rows, whatever), not the other one's first. So you get it. And to get the second'query's metadata you have to ask a database for it. The process is explained in my article: [Treating PHP delusions - The only proper PDO tutorial: Running multiple queries with PDO](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#multiquery). Basically `PDOStatement::nextRowset()` is what you need.

Comment: Ah. Makes perfect sense... the first query provides the row count. Ding. As for not wrapping these in a single prepared statement, I basically thought I was saving cycles and avoiding latency by preparing it only once... it's not an emulated statement (unless emulation kicks on automatically for multiple statements in a single PDO lexecution... was that the implication?) Also - is there any performance penalty to using SET rather than inline @var:= within SELECT? In fact I wrote it with SET to clarify the purpose of the query.

Comment: I'm also confused about your statement that in emulation mode "a placeholder with same name could be used any number of times in the same query, while corresponding variable have to be bound only once" but that it does not apply in normal mode. AFAIK I am not running any of this in emulation mode, and I am able to execute with an array(":var"=>$var) where ":var" shows up multiple times in the query, without any error from mysql. Maybe this is just supported now in PHP 7 ?

Comment: You *are* using the emulation mode. You don't save any cycles. There are no performance implications in either way. Performance is a complex topic and your concerns are totally mis-aimed here.

Comment: I have setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false) when I connect to the database. How am I using emulation mode?